# How to get distinct values of all columns in a table using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have a table which is going to dynamically change. It might have thousands of columns in it.

I need a way to find the distinct values in each column whenever I run a SQL Query.

Comment: can you describe the need for thousand of columns in it. Eyebrows raised.

Comment: @Drew Haha. I thought he said thousands of rows before you pointed this out.

Comment: its a dataset for data mining. U can expect 2000 columns * 1,000,000 rows

Comment: Good luck breaking your database.

Comment: Why would it break. MY DB is hosted on a server which has amazing hardware capabilities. Plus the environment is capable of handling that kind of data. Would appreciate if you could help me to find a solution than discouraging.

Comment: This sounds like it's going to go very, very wrong

Comment: And that's me putting a positive spin on it

Comment: i think following link will be useful for you before designing table https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/column-count-limit.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible justification for a table with this many columns. Your schema design is wrong.

With good hardware and appropriate indexes mysql can handle millions, or even hundreds of millions of rows, but columns is another story. Even if there was some design justification for thousands of columns there are physical limits within MySQL that would prohibit it, roughly as follows (my figures might not be up to date with the latest versions of MySQL - I'll try to verify later):

4096 columns: theoretical or 'hard' limit for number of columns.

2,829 columns : actual physical limit of a myisam table

1000 columns: hard limit for innodb

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE `table_no1` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `column0001` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `column0002` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
    `column0003` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
    `column0004` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
    .
    .
    .       
    `column2000` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

i also assume that you have a good program to analyze this data and for that program you are requesting this query.

You can use following queries to get distinct values

```
select DISTINCT(column0001) from table_no1;
select DISTINCT(column0002) from table_no1;
```

But thats not efficient. So you need to create this query dynamically by using your program. For that you have to find column names dynamically. For that you can use following query

```
    select COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.`COLUMNS` 
where TABLE_SCHEMA='your_database_name' and TABLE_NAME='table_no1'
```

Above query will give column names of that table. From that you can create your distinct query dynamically and retrieve individual column distinct values.